# issue with variable scope in foreach condition

Tags: php

let have a look in my script. below i am getting no values in while i am assigning the value to variable $specdata

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "select * from productrates");
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
  echo "<div class='box-body'>";

  $header='';
  $rowdata='';

$header='<tr>';

$field= mysqli_fetch_fields($result);


foreach ($field as $val) {

    if($val->name !="specs") 
    {
    $header.= "<th style='background:#E1E1E1'>".$val->name."</th>";

    }


}


$header.='</tr>';

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

    $field= mysqli_fetch_fields($result);
    $rowdata.="<tr class='linehover'>";
// in this section i want to show $specdata values in div id="specs"  

foreach ($field as $val) 
{
    $specdata =''; 

    if($val->name =="specs") 
    {

        $specdata = $row[1];
        echo $specdata;echo "<hr>";

    }
    if($val->name !="specs") 
    {
        if($val->name == "Product")
        {
            $rowdata.= "<td class='nohover'>".$row[$val->name]."<div id='specs'>".$specdata."</div></td>";

        }
        else
        {
            $rowdata.= "<td>".$row[$val->name]."</td>";
        }
    }
}
$rowdata.='</tr>';


} 
}

mysqli_free_result($result);

echo '<table class="table table-bordered"  id="pricelist">'.$header.$rowdata.'</table></div>';

// but every i am getting null value in that div
```

Comment: What value would you expect it to hold? You initialize it with an empty string..

Comment: do you get value in `$row` ? where you define `$rowdata` ?

Comment: And the two if blocks are mutually exclusive

Comment: @Steve i assigning the value to $specdata in if condtion and want to hold it and show it in the div id='specs'

Comment: @Rishi my rest code is working fine.

Comment: You only set the value when `if($val->name =="specs")`, but you are then trying to use it when `if($val->name !="specs")`.  It will _never_ be the case that both of those conditions are true.  That's what Steve is saying.

Comment: @PatrickQ   echo $specdata; shows the value while i run the code. how do i show the value of $specdata

Comment: dear @Steve find my full script.

Answer (score 0):

Let's chop the unimportant bits out and look at this

```
foreach ($field as $val) 
{
    $specdata =''; 

    if($val->name =="specs") 
    {
        $specdata = $row[1]; // no clue what $row[1] holds
        echo $specdata; echo "<hr>";
    }
    if($val->name !="specs") 
    {
        echo $specdata; // $specdata = '';
    }
}
```

Remember, `$specdata` is being set to an empty string every time the loop starts over. So even if you set it to `$row[1]` this time, it will be an empty string on the next iteration. So `if($val->name !="specs")` will always give you an empty string.

Comment: so should i declare that variable $specdata before foreach loop.

Comment: Moving the variable is only half the story. You have a section where the value isn't set to anything. Just moving the variable would probably get you a value, but not necessarily the right value

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the value of '$val->name'? because if it is different from "specs"
it will not pass on your first condition:

*if($val->name =="specs")*

just will not fill the variable $specdata

just to give you a hint it might be better to build this code to switch case like:

```
foreach ($field as $val)
{
    $specdata = '';    
    switch ($val->name) {
        case "specs":
          $specdata = $row[1];
          echo $specdata;echo "<hr>";
        break;

        case "Product":
           $rowdata.= "<td class='nohover'>".$row[$val->name]."<div id='specs'>".$specdata."</div></td>";
        break;

        default:
            $rowdata.= "<td>".$row[$val->name]."</td>";   
}
```

Comment: check also the variable "$row[1]" because it is not in the code you sent